# New pump, same problems

Tags: electrical, well-pump, pressure

Saturday my father and I replaced our well pump as it had gone bad earlier in the week as well as the pressure switch. Today we lost water again. We have a 3/4 hp well pump as well as a 40/60 pressure switch. For some reason the pressure won't go above 40 psi. Any ideas on what could be the issue and what a solution might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pipe leaking or low water level in the well.

Comment: Or bad pressure switch.

Answer (score 2):

how did you know the pump and pressure switch "went bad".   Most likely is that the production amount  of the well  took a turn for the worse and the pump was "sucking air" .  Solution:  Get a well guy out there with measuring electrodes to determine the static water level (IE w/o the pump running) and then then the water level after it's been running for a while.  Then compare to the depth of the pump and figure out if  the well production isn't good enough.  2 fixes:  install depth measuring equipment to turn off the pump when the water level gets too low or reduce the size of the pump to match the capacity of the well.